# Opening/using a table up in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a simple tab-separated text file that I want Ruby to read every value in the second column and write out a text file with each table value and another number. I was wondering how might I go about doing this (probably using some kind of loop).

Thanks

Comment: perhaps you could post a sample of your tab-separated text file, and an example how the output should look like. Because right now I don't really understand what you want. Especially the part about "write out a text file with each table value and another number"

Comment: @Bragboy: I never knew what accepting answers were. How do I accept answers?

@Jens F: Here is some text. I put the file on Rapidshare because I'm not sure about how to format on this window: http://rapidshare.com/files/407309823/ident_data.txt

I want the output to look like:
http://rapidshare.com/files/407310127/output.txt

Basically just a text file that has an ID number I will assign and the number from the table (both separated by a comma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open("output.txt", "w") do |output_file|
  File.open("input.txt") do |input_file|
    input_file.each_line do |line|
      values = line.split("\t")
      output_file.puts "#{values[1]} anothervalue"
    end
  end
end
```